# Visual Studio 2019 - don't insert a linebreak when opening curly braces (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, formatting, settings, line-breaks

I want to declare a variable like this:

```
int foo {5};
```

But as soon as I open the first curly brace, VS does this instead

```
int foo { 

}
```

I've spent a long time trying to find the relevant option but haven't had any luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Click "Options" in the upper toolbar, go to "text editor" in the left menu in the appeared window, choose "C++", "Formatting" and order Visual Studio to never newline such statements.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the issue at vs2019. I suggest you could try to `reset settings`.

Tools->Import and Export Settings...->Reset all Settings->Next->"No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings"->Next->General->Finish

[image]

[image]

[image]